# How can I prevent Webpack 5 (or one of its plugins) from stripping `@charset` from my exported CSS?

Tags: webpack, sass-loader, webpack-5

I have a Webpack 5 project, where I'm trying to prepend `@charset "UTF-8";` to my CSS files in an effort to address [this issue with Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17644). However, when Webpack is in `production` mode, I cannot get this code to remain, even though I have it in my original Sass file.

If I switch the `mode` to `none` or `development`, then the exported CSS is not minified (i.e., line breaks are there), and the `@charset` line remains.  Also note that I've removed the CSS minifier from the optimization.minifier list, yet the CSS code continues to get some sort of minifiying/processing.

FWIW, I did try the suggested answer in this [related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023438/webpack-scss-charset-and-import-problems) of disabling imports on `css-loader`, but that didn't help.

**Update (as noted in comments):**
Per connexo's suggestion, I removed the sass-loader, and the charset now line remains in the output (even after re-adding my CSS minifier). If I run sass from the command line (`./node_modules/sass/sass.js --no-charset main.scss test.css`) then the charset line also remains. There is a `--no-charset` option on sass, which when used will remove the charset line.    `{loader: "sass-loader", options: {sassOptions: {charset: true}}}` as my loader, but that didn't help

---

I have a sample project [here](https://github.com/pydolan/webpack-test), but you can also view the files below:

**Webpack config:**

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: "./main.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("./dist/"),
    filename: '[name].min.js',
    publicPath: "dist/",
    clean: true,
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, options: { publicPath: "./" } },
          { loader: "css-loader", options: { sourceMap: false } },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: { postcssOptions: { plugins: ['autoprefixer'] }},
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].min.css' }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    //
    // Explicitly excluding CSS minifier, but the CSS is still minified with @charset removed:
    //
    // minimizer: [
    //   `...`,
    //   new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    // ],
  },
};
```

**main.scss**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
#test:after {
  content: "✔️ ❤️";
}
```

**main.js**

```js
import "./main.scss";
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "test";
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.34.0",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.37.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try naming the file `main.css` and remove `sass-loader` from the equation, just to be sure it's not coming from that side. Just as a sidenote: As the world is quickly approaching the use of real modules in browsers, I'd suggest to stay away from any ways that don't translate to releasing modules, that is, which only works due to the build tools you're using.

Comment: It is indeed sass-loader: removing it from the loader list and the output (even after re-adding my CSS minifier) has the charset line remain.  If I run sass from the command line (`./node_modules/sass/sass.js --no-charset main.scss test.css`) then the charset line also remains. There is a `--no-charset` option on sass, which when used will remove the charset line. 

fwiw, I also just tried ` {loader: "sass-loader", options: {sassOptions: {charset: true}}}`, but that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @connexo for helping me realize sass-loader was the culprit, and after digging around, I found the "compressed" `outputFormat` – turned on by default if `outputFormat` is not specified and webpack's mode is "production" – was removing the charset line.  Thus my fix is to use the "expanded" outputFormat:

```
    {
      loader: "sass-loader",
      options: { sassOptions: { outputStyle: "expanded" }},
    },
```

Comment: Did this change still keep the `@charset` line or did it simply disable the compressing of unicode chars? I mean, if the character isn't compressed to begin with, probably there's no need for the `@charset` statement.

Comment: This change keeps the `@charset` line, but I'm unsure on it's impact otherwise (been a while since I worked in this code)